# jQquery AutoComplete fails to complete a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

By following http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/php-autocomplete-tutorial-using-jquery/
I wrote this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#member").on('input',function(e){
    var member = jQuery("#member").val(); 
   // alert(member);
    jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?=bloginfo('url')?>/wp-content/themes/hades/process_data_db.php",
            data:{getmember:member},
            success:function(data){
                //jQuery("#member").val(data.member);
                //alert(data);
                jQuery("#member").autocomplete({
                        source:data,
                        minLength:1});

            }
        });
});

});
</script>
```

to get the json data from php code file and then to autocomplete the textbox of the form named `member`. Now this code is working fine.Its returing this Json Data:

```
[{"value":"NameA,IND"},{"value":"NameB,BNP-A"},}]
```

But its fail to call autocomplete function to bind values to textbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#member").on('input',function(e){
var thiselem=$(this);
    var member = jQuery("#member").val(); 
   // alert(member);
    jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?=bloginfo('url')?>/wp-content/themes/hades/process_data_db.php",
            data:{getmember:member},
            success:function(data){
                //jQuery("#member").val(data.member);
                //alert(data);
                thiselem.autocomplete({
                        source:data,
                        minLength:1});

            }
        });
```

Comment: its still not getting the data